# How to avoid too many context.loads() in office-js

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I've read Michael Zlatkovsky's very excellent "Building Office Add-ins", and one of the things he says is attempt to avoid costly `async` calls to `context.load()`. He mentions that he would be hard pressed to find a scenario where he would need more than 2.

My question is this: If processing all the paragraphs in the entire document, I need to get at some very deeply nested elements (e.g. `document.paragraphs.paragraph.listItem.siblingIndex`). If I start from the document, the only way I can see to do this is:

```
paragraphs =  context.document.body.paragraphs;
paragraphs.load("items");
await context.sync();
for (var i =0; i<paragraphs.items.length; i++){
      paragraphs.items[i].load("listItemOrNullObject");
}
await context.sync();

//.... Then iterate through every item in paragraph to load(siblingIndex)

await context.sync();

//finally am able to process stuff that requires properties from all nested levels
```

Is this the correct way to go about this? i.e. one `sync()` call for each nested level for which one needs properties? Seems like many async calls to `sync()`. Is this avoidable in any way? I would imagine this is a common use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load properties from deep levels by using forward slashes in the parameter that you pass to the load method. This technique lets you load nested levels with a single context.sync().

The following code is from the same book you mentioned gets the `name` property of all the columns in all the tables in all the worksheets:

```
Excel.run(async (context) => {
 workbook.load("worksheets/tables/columns/name");

 await context.sync();

 var secondColumnOfFirstTableOnThirdSheet =
  workbook
 .worksheets.items[2]
 .tables.items[0]
 .columns.items[1];

 console.log("The ridiculously-nested column name was " +
 secondColumnOfFirstTableOnThirdSheet.name);

}).catch(...);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for paragraphs.load("paragraph/listItem/siblingIndex"). Console says siblingIndex is not available. Also tried paragraphs.load("item/listItem/siblingIndex"). I must be missing someing simple?

Comment: @Andrew This more specific problem isn't quite the same as the general question about minimizing loads that you started with. Can I ask you to create a new question? You could title it something like "Multilevel load() not working as expected". Also please include a complete Word.run function that isn't working. That makes it easier to understand what you're trying to achieve. Thanks!